# Getting "Variable data not initialized" error even though it's initialized

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

I haven't touched Java in a while, so I am a bit rusty on some the details.

I am trying to read from a file that is full of numbers all on their own line. The first number in the file tells me how many other numbers there are in the file so I can appropriately size my array. I am trying to take these numbers and put them in an array of ints, but I keep getting "error: variable data might not have been initialized" on my return statement. I know this has to be something simple, but I can't for the life of me find out what simple thing I am doing wrong.

```
public static int[] numbers(String filename)
{
    int[] data;

    try
    {
        FileReader input = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(input);

        int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
        data = new int[arraySize];

        for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++)
        {
            data[x] = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
        }

        buffer.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading: "+e.getMessage());
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: The array called data is not initialized. Initialize it with `int[] data = new int[x] `,  where x is the size of it.

Comment: Actually all you need is `int[] data = null;` (at the very top).  The problem is the part where you initialize it in the try clause may never occur.

Comment: Specifically, if the first line of the `try` fails, it never gets set.  You can also initialize it in the `catch` block (to default `null` maybe or `new int[0]`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Both rgettman's and Kritner's suggestions worked for compiling anyways. I will play around with both and see which one I like better. I apologize for such a simple question. I had another old program that is almost identical to what I posted and it worked like a charm so I was super confused. But it's taken care of now! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is an exception thrown in the `try` block, then `data` might not have been initialized by the time it's returned.

Initialize it to something when you declare it, even if the value is `null`, to satisfy the compiler.

On the other hand, it looks like `IOException` is the only exception to be thrown here.  Alternatively, you could have your method be declared to throw `IOException`, and remove the `try`-`catch` block so that `data` is always initialized if the `return` statement is executed.  You would of course need to catch the exception in the method that calls your `numbers` method.

Comment: This worked beautifully! I am going to play around with this and Kritner's suggestion to see which one I like better myself!

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you are initializing your **data** array inside of your try block, but if your try block catches an exception the **data** array may not be initialized but will be returned anyway.

Initialize your array outside of the try-catch:

For example:

```
 int[] data = new int[1]; //default initialization
```

Answer (score 2):

this is due to initialization in your try/catch block, if an exception were to be thrown prior to being initialized in the try/catch block, the array could potentially never be instantiated.

I would think just setting the array length to 1 or null at declaration would fix your issue

```
int[] data = new int[1];
try
// the rest
```

or

```
int[] data = null;
```

Comment: Initializing to null took care of the compiling issues. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions that are slightly different from the other answers (only slightly).  If there is an exception, then you should either 1) throw an exception (like `RuntimeException`) or 2) just return `null` (my guess is that you don't expect an exception to actually be thrown).

```
public static int[] numbers(String filename)
{
    BufferedReader buffer = null;
    try
    {
        final FileReader input = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(input);

        final int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
        final int[] data = new int[arraySize];

        for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++)
        {
            data[x] = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
        }

        buffer.close();
        return data;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        // a NumberFormatException may be thrown which will leave
        //   the buffer open, so close it just in case
        if(buffer != null)
            buffer.close();
    }
    // else there was an exception, return null
    return null;
}
```

Comment: this would work under the assumption it's ok to swallow an exception in this block though right?

Comment: Well my code snippet didn't throw an exception.  Something has to be done if an exception occurs either because you catch the thrown exception or because you check whether or not `null` is returned.  Certainly main cannot continue if this method fails (I'm assuming).